# Program for context indexed search in desktop

Tags: 12.04, search, .desktop

Is there any app similar to Google Desktop? I need to find files with key words that are source files or *.doc(x)/odt documents.

Comment: It seems that my answer do not reflect main idea due to my imperfect english. I was need to find files that **contain** text I describe with help of key words. Google Desktop was able to do that, but it is closed for now. I have solved an issue with help of _recoll_. This program also can perform context search such as Google Desktop. Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity will do that for you already.  Press the super key, select files, and type odt or whatever you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, Unity is designed to do that actually. :)

Comment: @fabricator4, will it also index data mounted with /etc/fstab by default (in some "/mnt/mounted_volume1")?

Comment: It appears to find anything mounted in ~/ but not in /mnt or /media.  Installing tracker-gui also installs "search & indexing" where you can specify other directories such as removable media, and how long to keep the data for. I believe it is supposed to tie-in with the same index, so items can then also be searched for in the dash.